# How to filter multiple date ranges

Tags: r, apache-spark, datetime, dplyr

I have a dataset with lots of dates. I would like to delete all the dates not present in the time interval from January 1st to February 2nd of all the years available (2015,2016,2017 and 2018)

```
  new_data <- my_data %>%
      filter(data > "2015-01-01" & data <"2015-02-02" & 
               data > "2016-01-01" & data <"2016-02-02" &
               data > "2017-01-01" & data <"2017-02-02" &
               data > "2018-01-01" & data <"2018-02-02")
```

I tried this command but I don't get the desired result:

```
   sdf_nrow(new_data)
    0
```

I'm using spark and that's why I have to use dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re currently saying “is the date in Jan 2015 *and at the same time* in Jan 2016 … etc”. This is obviously never true, since these date ranges don’t overlap. You need to use “or” instead of “and”:

```
new_data <- my_data %>%
    filter(
        data > "2015-01-01" & data < "2015-02-02" |
        data > "2016-01-01" & data < "2016-02-02" |
        data > "2017-01-01" & data < "2017-02-02" |
        data > "2018-01-01" & data < "2018-02-02"
    )
```

Furthermore, make sure that your `data` (not `date`?) column actually refers to a *date* and has an appropriate type that does the right thing when compared to a character string.

Beware with operator precedence: this works because `&` has higher precedence than `|` but many people find it more readable to be explicit and put parentheses around the inner `… & …` expressions.